# How can I sort a group of linked nodes. (Sorting a sequentially linked Node in order of a priority value.)

Tags: java, nodes

We learned to use Nodes just recently and for a project we've been tasked to sort the Nodes based on a given priority value that each item in the Node will have. I tried this on paper (making boxes and giving values to then match) and it made sense but when implementing, it gives me an NullPointerException. Any help would be great. I don't know if I need to give more information if the question doesn't make sense but I can if need be, and sorry my english isn't that great.

Code used to add a new node:

```
private void pushJob(PrintJob n) {
    this.jobs = new Node(n, this.jobs);


}
```

And the code used to Sort the items (they are sorted in increasing priority):

```
private void sortJobs() {
    Node p, q, r;

    p = this.jobs;
    q = null;

    while (p != null) {
        q = p;
        p = p.next;

        if (q.item.getPriority() > p.item.getPriority() && q != null && p != null) {
            r = q;
            q = p;
            p = r;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your code, but something I see right away is that in your while loop, you check to see if `P != null`, if it not null you assign `p = q` and `p = p.next`.

However, if p.next was null, p is now null. This means when you compare `q.item.getPriority > p.item.getPriority` it will throw an exception when trying to call .item on the now null p.

If you check your last condition of `p != null` first, then you should not run into the problem because the rest of the conditions will not be check (because && is a short-circuit operator). Or, you can have your while loop check `p.next != null` instead of `p != null`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, and as you said I did add an if statement to check if p == null and if it is to break the while loop and that did fix the NullPointer but that was only a temp solution, as after that the loop would go on forever for some reason after i would add the next item to the node. But thank you and I'll keep working on it to see what I can do, and sorry the code was confusing. I'm still learning.

Comment: When you push a job, what is `this` referring to?